# Sentence Spacing

Tags: html, css, typography, spacing

What is the best way to present the additional spacing that should come between sentences (using [X]HTML+CSS)?

```
<p>Lorem ipsum.  Dolor sit amet.</p>
               ^^ wider than word spacing
```

Since HTML and XML both require whitespace folding, the above two spaces must behave as a single space.

What options are there?  There are a few obvious ones below, what others exist?  (Anything in CSS3?)  What drawbacks, if any, exist for the these, including across different browsers?  (How do the non-breaking spaces below interact with line wrapping?)

- `..ipsum. &nbsp;Dolor..`
- `..ipsum.&nbsp; Dolor..`
- `..ipsum.&nbsp;&nbsp;Dolor..`

---

There's a lot of FUD on the net which claims this was invented for typewriters, but you can see it in documents such as the U.S. [Declaration of Independence](http://www.solarnavigator.net/history/explorers_history/USA_declaration_of_independence.jpg).  (And yes, I realize you shouldn't follow all the conventions from over two hundred years ago, the DoI is merely a handy example showing this predates typewriters and monospaced fonts.)  Or a typographer claiming that the [additional space is distracting](http://www.itcfonts.com/Ulc/4111/DoubleSpaces.htm)—after changing the background color so the example cannot be anything else!

To put it bluntly, while I appreciate opinions and discussion on whether additional spacing should be used or not (which isn't programming related), that is not what I'm asking.  Assume this a requirement, what is the best way to implement it?

Comment: Yes, there are different rules in different parts of the world, I thought it was implied I'm following rules which specify this. :)  (The only downside is I apparently have to make a trade-off due to HTML..)

Comment: This whole "two space after a period nonsense" was invented when we used monospaced typefaces and dumb output devices. Modern typography engines do this for you. Do *not* override their default behavior!

Comment: Frank: The Declaration of Independence was not typed, yet uses this.  Unfortunately I cannot use a modern typography engine such as TeX, I must use HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap each sentence in a span, and style the span perhaps. (Not a great solution).

Comment: I had thought of this and almost included it in my "obvious solution" list, but discarded it.  However, it is currently the only suggested solution that meets the requirements with the least presentation drawbacks.  (Source code drawbacks notwithstanding.)  I used padding-right in my sample.

Comment: I'm curious why it was downvoted, could you leave a comment?

Comment: Yeah, this idea is possibly the most practical solution today, even though it does involve adding a lot of markup.

Comment: It's interesting because perhaps there is a semantic reason to wrap a complete utterance (usually a sentence) in a span. For children learning, foreign languages, blind readers and so forth it might come in handy somehow. I'm not saying I'd do it myself, but I don't see a semantic reason to dismiss it outright. Other solutions have suggested adding spaces of some sort, and since we are adding something anyway I'd thought along the lines of 'why not this as you're not affecting the content'.

Comment: I've run into issues with nested tags, but only because I wasn't using this before, and they were easy enough to resolve.  This really is a content issue better resolved by a character than XML tree---saying "end of a sentence, *right here*", just like space characters between words say "end of word, start a new one"---but emsp and related are currently unsatisfactory.  I guess that character is supposed to be periods, but it's overloaded too much to easily distinguish.  Anyway, I implemented this solution for the project.

Comment: See http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/html-sentences.html for a more complete version of this: `p { word-spacing: 0.25em; }`, `.sntc { word-spacing:0; }`, and `<p><span class="sntc">This is the first sentence.</span><span class="sntc">This is the second.</span></p>`

Answer (score 13):

You can use `white-space: pre-wrap` to preserve sequences of spaces, while still wrapping text:

```
<p style="white-space: pre-wrap;">Lorem ipsum.  Dolor sit amet.</p>
```

This is not supported in IE until IE 8 in IE 8 mode, nor in Firefox until 3.0.

You could also use `&emsp;` or `&ensp;` for spaces one `em` or one `en` wide. I do not know how widespread support of these is, but they seem to work on the latest WebKit and Firefox on Mac OS X.

A sequence of two `&nbsp;` characters will prevent line breaks in that space; that's what `&nbsp;` means, non-breaking space. The sequence `A sentence. &nbsp;Another.` causes the `&nbsp;` to appear on the second line, indenting text slightly, which is probably undesireable. The sequence `A sentence.&nbsp; Another.` works fine, with line breaking and not adding any extra indentation, though if you use it in justified text, with the `&nbsp;` at the end of the line, it will prevent that line from being properly justified. `&nbsp;` is intended for the case of writing someone's name, like `Mr.&nbsp;Torvalds`, or an abbreviation ending with a `.`, in which typographical convention says that you shouldn't split it across lines in order to avoid people being confused and thinking the sentence has ended.

So, using sequences of `&nbsp;` is undesirable. Since this is a stylistic effect, I'd recommend using `white-space: pre-wrap`, and accepting that the style will be a bit less than ideal on platforms that don't support it.

**edit**: As pointed out in the comments, `white-space: pre-wrap` does not work with `text-align: justify`. However, I've tested out a [sampler of different entities](http://ephemera.continuation.org/stackoverflow/spacing.html) using [BrowserShots](http://browsershots.org/http://ephemera.continuation.org/stackoverflow/spacing.html) (obnoxious ads, and somewhat flaky and slow, but it's a pretty useful service for the price, which is free). It looks like a pretty wide variety of browsers, on a pretty wide variety of platforms, support `&ensp;` and `&emsp;`, a few that don't still use spaces so the rendering isn't too bad, and only IE 6 on Windows 2000 actually renders them broken, as boxes. BrowserShots doesn't let me choose the exact browser/OS combos I want, so I can't choose IE 6 on XP to see if that's any different. So, that's a plausible answer as long as you can live with IE 6 on Win2K (and maybe XP) broken.

Another possible solution would be to find (or create) a font that has a kerning pair for the ". " combination of characters, to kern them more widely apart. With `@font-face` support in all of the major browsers at this point, including IE back to IE 5.5 (though IE uses a different format than the other browsers), using your own font is actually becoming reasonable, and falling back to the users default font if not supported would not break anything.

A final possibility might be to talk the CSS committee into adding a style feature that would allow you to specify that you want wider spacing at the end of sentences (which would be determined by a period followed by a space; acronyms and abbreviations would need an `&nbsp;` in order to avoid getting the wider space). The CSS committee is currently discussing adding more advanced typography support, so now might be a good time to start discussing such a feature.

Comment: This disables `text-align: justify`, otherwise it seems like it would be the best answer.

Comment: Hmm. If you care about exact spacing, why would you use `justify`? In that case, then, I would test out `&ensp;` on a variety of browsers, and see if that works for you.

Comment: I use justified text for other reasons, but sentence spacing should still be wider than word spacing.

Comment: Can't arbitrarily kern ". ", as it appears with "Dr. Z" or even "U.S. of A.".  ensp and emsp have the same problem as nbsp, in that you get whitespace before and after individual lines, but I do agree they are better choices than nbsp.

Comment: For those cases, what you would do is kern ". " but not ".&nbsp;". I wouldn't guarantee that browser rendering engines will actually use different kerning for those two pairs; in fact, I believe that WebKit doesn't do kerning at all (I know it doesn't do ligatures for English text). So, really, until the browsers get a lot more serious about good typography, and are willing to sacrifice rendering speed for it, I don't think that there will be an ideal solution for your problem.

Comment: I initially missed your requirement of nbsp after non-sentence-terminating periods.  I think that would kill such a proposal for practical reasons, even if such interpretations required a special CSS property.  And yes, the additional rendering time (I couldn't measure it), and even extra bandwidth, wasn't an issue for me in this project.

Comment: I vote for &emsp; or &ensp; -- the latter is what I ended up using extensively on my own website.  This is the most semantically correct, and no longer seems to have any support shortcomings.  (Those who say intersentence spacing should be as narrow as interword spacing don't seem to read many actual books.)

Answer (score 7):

For all you 'antiquated' and 'mono-space-only' naysayers - Read a book. Professional publishers have used a single `&emsp;` between sentences for time immemorial, and THAT is where the monospace two-space standard came from. Learn from history instead of spouting rhetoric with no basis in fact. I have to admit, though, that an `&ensp;` looks better in most browsers: `&emsp;` is just too wide. What do you think of the readability of this paragraph? Stackoverflow's editor allows some HTML, and I'm using `&ensp;` between all sentences.

Comment: This seems much more like a comment than an answer...

Comment: @Syon, it's chatty, but it seems to be answering the question: "Use `&ensp;` or, if you think it looks good, `&emsp;`"

Comment: This contracts a well researched article here http://www.heracliteanriver.com/?p=324 - which notes that em-quadrat (viz. a double-space) was used after a sentence-ending period for centuries, up until the 1930s or so.

Answer (score 2):

`&nbsp;` isn't the correct character to use, semantically speaking. It's a non-breaking space: a space which won't be used as a line break. Perhaps use a space an a `&ensp;` or a single `&emsp;`, or (my personal recommendation) don't bother with the antiquated double-space style on your page.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to throw out there that if your goal is to override the default browser whitespace implementation to provide "proper" sentence spacing, there is actually [some debate](http://desktoppub.about.com/cs/typespacing/a/onetwospaces.htm) as to what constitutes proper spacing. It seems that the double-space "standard" is most likely just a carryover from when typewriters used monospace fonts. Money quote:

> **The Bottomline**: Professional
>   typesetters, designers, and desktop
>   publishers should use one space only.
>   Save the double spaces for
>   typewriting, email, term papers (if
>   prescribed by the style guide you are
>   using), or personal correspondence.
>   For everyone else, do whatever makes
>   you feel good.

Unless you have this as a strict requirement, it does not seem worth the effort to try and "fix."  (I realize this is not an answer to your stated question per se, but wanted to make sure that you are aware of this info as it might influence your decision to spend a lot of time on it.)

Comment: Interestingly the poll on the linked page (currently 14584 votes) has 47% in favor of additional sentence spacing, with an additional 8% that apparently use or work with the additional spacing daily (the third option).

Comment: Personally I still double-space most of my writing out of habit, although I've noticed that when typing in IM or on my iPhone I've changed to single space to save keystrokes (not sure why I still use 2 in other media...) I think it's become more of a stylistic thing nowadays than a matter of correctness.  I'd be curious to hear what a professional editor would say about it.

Comment: Various sources I've read agree that after WW2, companies like magazines and book publishers adjusted many previous practices in the interest of saving paper and cost; and that such practice became precedent for today.  That justification doesn't apply to me (but not obviously so, it's certainly possible to use HTML for print layout), but my audience is different from theirs anyway.

Answer (score 1):

&nbsp; is the worst possible method, as it disrupts justification.  Pre-wrap as suggested gives coarse control but can't be justified.  There are other space entities like &thinspace; and &nspace;, as well as a bunch of Unicode space characters that should give somewhat better control and should not break justification.   These entities are the best non-CSS solution in my opinion.

For better control you need a CSS solution.  You can either span the sentences, the obvious choice, or you can span the space between sentences.  The latter to me seems more incorrect, but it is easier to achieve, especially if you have the common two-space typing habit - you can simply search and replace all period-space-space with a span around a space.  I have some javascript that does this on the fly for blogger.

Don't use the box model (padding-right) as it will break the right margin of fully justified text (and even if not fully justified, causes lines to wrap "early").  If you are spanning the space between sentences you can just alter the word-spacing on these elements.  If you are wrapping sentences, you can set your paragraph or other container to have bigger word-spacing, and the set the sentences back to normal, or you can do it in one step with the after selector:

.your_sentence_class:after { content:" "; word-spacing:0.5em; }