# How to write a quomma

Tags: html, unicode, punctuation

I'd like to start using question marks at the end of clauses as well as sentences. To indicate this I would like to use a question mark with a comma underneath, which I'd like to call a quomma.

There doesn't seem to be a Unicode code point for this unconventional punctuation, so what is the most Web-friendly way of doing this?

- The combining diacritical mark doesn't seem to work anywhere I've tried it: ?̦ (Though is there something which prevents overlappingʔ̦ because the glottal stop mark, which looks almost like a dotless question mark (ʔ) does seem to work, as you just saw!)
- SVG support is not widespread, and this would require a per-font SVG anyway.
- A raster image seems a bit of a crap solution.
- Is there some cheeky but not-too-hacky HTML/CSS?
- Any other ideas?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what is the purpose of this?

Comment: Is this intended to emulate the speaking patterns of tweenaged girls? "Like, I was at the mall? and I saw this guy? and he smiled at me? and I was like OMG!"

Comment: I admit it is slightly frivolous, but I just occasionally want to end clauses with a question mark! And also what Mike said.

Comment: close it? Why? It's an interesting question... Just because you don't understand why someone wants to do something, that's no bloody reason to close it.

Comment: Who is voting to close this? It's an exotic question, but *not a real question*? Wtf?

Comment: Agree 100% it's a real question.  We should not judge whether his software requirement is valid, but whether the programming question he asks is a real programming question.  Which it is.  Pekka gave what seems like a good answer.

Comment: @Statto: If you want to end them with a question mark, why not just put in...a question mark? :) Why invent a character?

Comment: Real question or not, I want my click back.

Comment: @Jonathan Apparently using the question-mark mid-sentence was valid in the past, but I think it would look pretty weird with a lower-case letter after it in modern usage. That said, depending on how hacky the solution ends up being, I may just use a normal question mark anyway!

Comment: @Statto: This may have been the case in...the past...but today it's just going to confuse your readers and cause them to think you don't understand proper punctuation ;)

Comment: +1 Interesting deviation from the typical questions here. Love it.

Comment: I can tell usage of this "quomma" is going to take off like crazy. Quick, someone tag this with `quomma` to get the taxonomist badge!

Comment: Since when is making up your own grammatical symbols programming related?

Comment: @gnovice: Since you ask how to do them in css/html.

Comment: Shouldn't we get the interrobang widely used first?, before approaching the quomma‽

Comment: You're asking about why a symbol which doesn't exist, doesn't exist. That's not a real question.

Comment: Re-read the question. He is asking how to synthesize a character that doesn't exist from pre-existing characters. That is a valid question.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the combining diatrics ([charts](http://unicode.org/charts/)), in particular U+0326 (COMBINING COMMA BELOW).

The HTML `&#x0294;&#x0326;` produces:

## ʔ̦

*Since this is unlikely to be a grapheme used in any existing language, whether that works or not on your browser may depend on a number of factors related to Unicode and font support.*

Comment: But that thing on the top is still a glottal stop mark, which doesn't look exactly like the top of a question mark to me?

Comment: This looks like two distinct characters in Firefox 3.0.5.

Comment: It also fails in Chrome 5.0.322.2 dev, fwiw.

Answer (score 3):

This one works inline; even IE can handle inline-block displays on span-elements:

```
<p>Some text with a quomma in it <span class="quomma">?<span class="c">,</span></span> and some more text</p>
```

CSS:

```
span.quomma {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

span.quomma .c {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: .1em;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Your solution works better @Harmen. I would upvote you but I'm out of votes. I'm deleting my answer.

Comment: +1 with the caveat that `inline-block` and firefox2 don't go well together.

Comment: Cheers @Doug :) Harmen's solution works in IE5, 6 and 7, which mine did not. So, credit to him for using `inline-block`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not a satisfactory answer, but you don't need a special symbol for this.  Simply use a question mark and continue the sentence as if it were a comma:

> Would you prefer some of a? is b more to your taste? or how about c?
>
> Like, I was at the mall? and I saw this guy? and he smiled at me? and I was like OMG!
>   
>     – [Mike Daniels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275695/how-to-write-a-quomma#comment-2238360)

I'm not sure of the history or whether it was ever mainstream, but I have seen it, on occasion, used clearly.  I doubt any style manual endorses it whole-heartedly—or even at all?—but since you're up for generating your own punctuation, that doesn't seem a huge concern.  At one time, wasn't it common to indicate sentence breaks [specially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972887/sentence-spacing)? or not?  Wouldn't such indication obviate the quomma? or is there still a need for it?  (Can I keep that up any longer?  Nope.)