# how to show two spaces at the end of a sentence (redux)

Tags: html, css, typography

Ok, deep breath.

Suppose one is using a monospace font and has three requirements.  This may or may not be wise; that's not what I'm asking.

1. Show two spaces at the end of each sentence in a web page, provided the sentence ends in midline.
2. But if the sentence ends in mid-paragraph but happens to approach the right margin, the final character (typically ".") should be able to nestle as close to that right margin as any other character in any other line.  That is, carefully tweaking the window width while viewing the test results ought to be able to squeeze out any space following the pre-gap text.
3. Similarly, no extraneous space must be introduced after the line break.

To be able to justify the text is not a requirement.

A similar question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972887/sentence-spacing).  But that thread has two problems (for me):

1. It was rightly closed, because the discussion bogged down in whether the requirement was wise in the first place.  I do not assert the wisdom of the above requirements; I simply ask the question.
2. The initiator did not seem to worry about requirement 2 above, so the discussion did not fully address it.

I have tried placing each of the following between two sentences.  Each of them either did not fulfill one of the requirements, or completely failed to allow a line break between the two sentences.  As you read this list, add semicolons where they seem appropriate; when I added them to the actual list, I got real spaces and stuff, not the names of the entities.

1. (space)(space)
2. &emsp&emsp
3. (space)&emsp
4. &emsp(space)
5. &ensp&ensp
6. (space)&ensp
7. &ensp(space)
8. &nbsp&nbsp
9. (space)&nbsp
10. &nbsp(space)
11. (space)(space-within-span)
12. (space-within-span)(space)
13. (space-within-span)(space-within-span)

In addition, I tried the `white-space: pre-wrap` idea, which failed requirement 2.

What do you suggest?  In my tests, the stylesheet is this:

```
P.intro
{
  font-family:      Courier, monospace;
}

P.prewrap
{
  font-family:      Courier, monospace;
  white-space:      pre-wrap;
}
```

... and the web page is this:

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</HEAD><BODY>
<P class=intro>
01 alpha spacespace  omega spacespace<BR>
<BR>
02 alpha &amp;emsp;&amp;emsp;&emsp;&emsp;omega &amp;emsp;&amp;emsp;<BR>
03 alpha space&amp;emsp; &emsp;omega space&amp;emsp;<BR>
04 alpha &amp;emsp;space&emsp; omega &amp;emsp;space<BR>
<BR>
05 alpha &amp;ensp;&amp;ensp;&ensp;&ensp;omega &amp;ensp;&amp;ensp;<BR>
06 alpha space&amp;ensp; &ensp;omega space&amp;ensp;<BR>
07 alpha &amp;ensp;space&ensp; omega &amp;ensp;space<BR>
<BR>
08 alpha &amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;omega &amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;<BR>
09 alpha space&amp;nbsp; &nbsp;omega space&amp;nbsp;<BR>
10 alpha &amp;nbsp;space&nbsp; omega &amp;nbsp;space<BR>
<BR>
11 alpha space-spanspace <SPAN> </SPAN>omega space-spanspace<BR>
12 alpha spanspace-space<SPAN> </SPAN> omega spanspace-space<BR>
13 alpha spanspace-spanspace<SPAN> </SPAN><SPAN> </SPAN>omega spanspace-spanspace<BR>
<BR>
0 2 4 6 8 0 2 4 6 8 0 2 4 6 8 0 2 4 6 8 0 2 4 6 8 0 2 4 6 8 0 2
<BR>
01 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9 1 3
</P>
<P class=prewrap>Lorem ipsum.  Dolor sit amet.</P>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: Hitham, &nbsp;&nbsp was test #8.  It failed to break the two words apart under any circumstances.

Comment: where is the semi-colon?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  In the actual test, I used the semicolons, as line 08 in the listed page shows (and has always shown).  But in the list of tests in the introduction, I left out the semicolons because that would have converted the names of entities into actual entities (spaces and such).  I edited the question to make this clear, but not in time for you to have seen it.  My apologies.  (Try &nbsp;&nbsp; yourself.  You'll see it doesn't allow the words on either side to split onto separate lines.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include this in your css file:

```
SPAN.eos
{
  word-spacing: 0.625em
}
```

Do this at the end of each midparagraph sentence:

```
finalword<SPAN class=eos>. B</SPAN>eginning
```